# Store user Data in a Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have created a form that will collect user data, store it in a `HashMap` and print the `HashMap` in the console. I have tried all ways I could think of but they are not working.
Here is what I've tried so far.

```
//This is the class that will store user data in a hashmap
public class userRegistrationData {
    
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> userData;
    
    public userRegistrationData() {
        RegistrationForm form = new RegistrationForm();
        userData = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
        
        String id = String.valueOf(form.getUserIdField());
        String firstName = String.valueOf(form.getFirstNameTextField());
        String lastName = String.valueOf(form.getLastNameTextField());
        String phone = String.valueOf(form.getPhoneTextField());
        String city = String.valueOf(form.getCityTextField());
        String createPassword = String.valueOf(form.getCreatePasswordField());
        String confirmPassword = String.valueOf(form.getConfirmPasswordField());
        
        userData.put(id, new ArrayList<String>());
        userData.get(id).add(id);
        userData.get(id).add(firstName);
        userData.get(id).add(lastName);
        userData.get(id).add(lastName);
        userData.get(id).add(phone);
        userData.get(id).add(city);
        userData.get(id).add(createPassword);
        userData.get(id).add(confirmPassword);
    }
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> formData() {
        return userData;    
    }
    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> getUserData() {
        return userData;
    }
    public void setUserData(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> userData) {
        this.userData = userData;
    }

    
}
//The action performed method which will listen to the submit button 
        

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        userRegistrationData data = new userRegistrationData();
        if(e.getSource().equals(submitBtn)) {
            if(data.getUserData().containsKey(getUserIdField())) {
                System.out.println(data.getUserData());
            }
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: "I have tried all ways I could think of but they are not working" - in what *way* is what you've tried not working?

Comment: Does the class RegistrationForm has actual data inside it when you instantiate it?

Comment: Yes, the registration has text fields where the data will be collected

Comment: That's not what Dan Serb asked. They asked if it has __actual data__. Having text fields is meaningless when you create the form and then read those text fields without giving a user the slightest chance to write something in those text fields.

Answer (score 0):

you can print it by this simple code:

```
data.getUserData().entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "\n" + 
Arrays.deepToString(entry.getValue().toArray()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a toString function in **userRegistrationData** class:

```
public void toString(String id) {
        System.out.println(userData.get(id));
}
```

In your **actionPerformed** function, simply call

```
data.toString(String.toValue(getUserIdField()));
```

Instead of printing the object in toString function, you can also return it to the actionPerformed function as String.